# Why does seaborn change the order of legend handles when the data is a list of nd arrays?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

When I plot a histogram with multiple data columns, the legend is displayed correctly when the data is given as pandas data frame but it seems that the order of the legend handles gets flipped when the data is given as a list of arrays.

For example this code:

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
x1 = np.random.normal(100, 25, 100)
x2 = np.random.normal(200, 25, 100)
x3 = np.random.normal(300, 25, 100)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(18, 8))

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([x1,x2,x3]).T, columns= ['x1', 'x2', 'x3'])
sns.histplot(df, bins=30, color=['r','g', 'b'], ax=axs[0])

sns.histplot([x1,x2,x3] , bins=30, color=['r','g', 'b'], ax=axs[1])
axs[1].legend(['x1','x2','x3'])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Strangely if I just get the handles from the axes and give it back, the order is fixed.

```
axs[1].legend((axs[1].get_legend().legendHandles), ['x1','x2','x3'])
```

Comment: sns may decide to plot from right column to left column, or to melt data with decreasing order of hue. That being said, the three colors `rgb` are not even used. You can also use `sns.histplot(df, bins=30, ax=axs[0], palette={'x1':'r','x2':'g','x3':'b'})` to ensure correct hue color.

Comment: `ax.legend()` isn't recommended when working with seaborn.  To change the legend properties and position, there is the `sns.movelegend(...)` function.  If you want to rename the hue values, the recommended way is to rename the values in the column used. To get a nice legend, working with a dataframe or a dictionary makes things easier. Also, to set a list of colors, you need `palette=['r','g','b']` instead of `color=`.  Your second example could work like `sns.histplot({'x1': x1, 'x2': x2, 'x3': x3}, bins=30, palette=['r', 'g', 'b'], ax=ax)`